# Can an Incubus and Succubus reproduce with each other?

Tags: demons

I know these demons reproduce with humans, however can they reproduce with each other?

Comment: Is there any mythological basis for either?

Comment: I don't know that's why I'm asking the question lmao

Comment: Do succubus produce reproductive cells? It is often said that succubus just steal human sperm for the incubus (who also has no seed).

Answer (score 2):

Originally, the Succubus and the Incubus were thought to be responsible for [sleep paralysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleep_paralysis), a frightening experience that is understandably associated with demonic forces.

As such, there is little basis to assume these demons mingle with each-other, as we only know of their interactions with humans. I'm sure there are later myths that consider this question, and may answer the question either in the positive, or the negative. However, that would only seem to an answer the question for demons in particular, and not specific to these demons.

So in short, not that we know of.

Comment: From what I've read, in Jewish belief, demons are capable of reproduction. In Christianity they aren't, and Islam I have no info on.

Comment: @Orionixe demon-demon reproduction? or human-demon ?

Comment: @Mauricio  And God said, "Let the land produce living creatures according to their kinds: livestock, creatures that move along the ground, and wild animals, each according to its kind." And it was so (Genesis 1:24). 

From this verse I guess Demons can reproduce with each other since God made it that only 2 beings from the same species can reproduce.

Comment: @Mauricio wait the Christian bishop Gregory of Nyssa described that demons could procreate with each other

Comment: If you have a citation on Demon-Demon reproduction, include it in your answer. It's always good to show what research you have done.