# Were Cambions originally the demon offspring of a Succubus and Incubus?

Tags: origins, demons, medieval-europe, witchcraft

The earliest evidenced appearance of the word "cambion" in the sense of an offspring of two demons is in the 1818 French-Language Dictionnaire Infernal. The 1825 edition of that book has the following entry: *CAMBION, -- Children of Demons. Delancre and Bodin believe that incubus demons can unite with succubus demons...*

In the *Encyclopedia of Occultism and Parapsychology* the cambions are again said to be the direct offspring of the incubus and the succubus, foregoing any need for human involvement.

Comment: What question do you have that you haven't already answered for yourself here? It seems the book you cite answers your title well enough, no?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cambion) suggests "cambion" was used as a word for changelings at least as early as the 13th century. These changelings were seen as sons of incubi demons, so that connection is still there (but no mention the mother is a succubus).

Comment: @towr Were these offspring demons or hybrids since there was no mention of a female demon? The 2 sources I quoted have mentioned born from 2 demons so I'm confused

Comment: I'm not sure. I haven't looked at the cited source (and I can't read Latin anyway). The section on human-demon hybrids on the wikipedia page says that the hybrid meaning emerged in the late 19th century, though. So that would suggest that before that they were considered pure demons.

Comment: This reminds me of this question https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/10317/can-an-incubus-and-succubus-reproduce-with-each-other